# Vue3 setup returned value can't be found in the rest of that component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

It says "anything returned here will be available for the rest of the component"(https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html#setup-component-option), but I got this error on c which is a variable returned in setup: Cannot find name 'c'.ts(2304).

```html
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
export default defineComponent({
  setup(props) {
    let c = 123;
    return { c }
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      c;
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to access the variables exposed via `setup` method using `this` keyword in your methods.

###### Warning:

But this is just a bad way to proceed because you are mixing `composition api` with `options api`. Refer to [this](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/vue-3-composition-api-vs-options-api/) thread to understand the difference between the two.

```js
Vue.createApp({
  setup(props) {
    let c = 123;
    return { c }
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      console.log(this.c);
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="increment">Increment</button>
</div>
```

###### Correct way achieving it using [Composition API](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#composition-api):

```js
Vue.createApp({
  setup(props) {
    const c = Vue.ref(123);
    const increment = () => c.value++;

    return {
      c,
      increment
    }
  },
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="app">
  <span>{{ c }}</span><br/><br/>
  <button @click="increment">Increment</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works well, but if I use <script setup> to declare c, it's both inaccessible whether using **this** keyword or not.
(no this: runtime error occurs but static type check is fine. with this: static type error.)
Actually I am migrating from vue2, otherwise I would prefer to use Composition API only, and I am just finding the best practice to declare a type-defined variable for accessing <VueComp ref="vuecomp"/>.Now I know  it can be achieved by using Composition API only, but what if I use option API? Use $ref!:{} to declare type?

Comment: Sorry, it's difficult to understand from this. What are you migrating to, Vue3? You are free to use either `Options API` or `Composition API`. Only thing to keep in mind is not to mix both. Regarding template ref, you can understand how to use them in both ways [here](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-template-refs.html) & [here](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html#usage-with-jsx). If you still have doubts, feel free to create a separate question with your approach in it and the community can guide you with the best practices. :-)

Comment: OK, Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to create a function in vue 3.

- Add inside the setup method ( better )

Here the this. do not exists, so you can write a simple function like

```
const add = () => ++c.value
```

Here, the istance do not exist yet, so you can write c without this.
Remember to export the function and create the c variable with ref or it won't update

- Use the method object like you did

You can use this way but you need to use **this.** param because the istance now exists